# My project doesnt' work in mikroC

Tags: mikroc

This is my project for reverse parking...this code is working without IF statements. When I put IF statements in code my hardware don't respond. (IF statements in the void main...)
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Thanks for help!

```
sbit LCD_RS at RD0_bit;
sbit LCD_EN at RD1_bit;
sbit LCD_D4 at RD2_bit;
sbit LCD_D5 at RD3_bit;
sbit LCD_D6 at RD4_bit;
sbit LCD_D7 at RD5_bit;

sbit LCD_RS_Direction at TRISD0_bit;
sbit LCD_EN_Direction at TRISD1_bit;
sbit LCD_D4_Direction at TRISD2_bit;
sbit LCD_D5_Direction at TRISD3_bit;
sbit LCD_D6_Direction at TRISD4_bit;
sbit LCD_D7_Direction at TRISD5_bit;
//inicializacija LCD modula

char message1[] = "Distance:";

char *dis = "000.0";

unsigned int dist;
float temp_value;
float x;
float y;

void Display_Distance() {
 if (dist/10000)
    dis[0] = dist/10000 + 48;         //stotice
 else 
      dis[0] = ' ';
 dis[1] = (dist/1000)%10 + 48;      // desetica
 dis[2] = (dist/100)%10 + 48;     // enica
 dis[4] = (dist/10)%10 + 48;      // decimalka
 Lcd_Out(2, 1, dis);              // izpis distance na LCD
}


void main() {
 Lcd_Init();
 Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
 Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF);
 Lcd_Out(1,1,message1);
 Lcd_Chr(2,7,'C');
 Lcd_Chr(2,8,'m');


 do {
    x = (float)ADC_Read(2);  //vrednost iz analognega kanala, kamor je senzor priklopljen
    y = (((x*5)/1023));      //pretvorba v volte
    if(y>0){
                 temp_value = (((log10(y))/(log10(0.98)))+62.6);     //funkcija grafa



             if(y<=0.8 && y>0.65)
                       temp_value = temp_value+10;
             else if(y<=0.65 && y>0.6)
                  temp_value = temp_value+17.5;
             else if(y<=0.6 && y>0.55)
                  temp_value = temp_value+13;
             else if(y<=0.55 && y>0.5)
                  temp_value = temp_value+3.5;
             else if(y>=2 && y<2.5)
                  temp_value = temp_value+1.3;
             else if(y>=2.5 && y<2.8)
                  temp_value = temp_value+4.5;



                 temp_value=temp_value*10000;
                 dist = temp_value/1000;
                 dist = dist*10;
                 Display_Distance();                 
                 Delay_ms(1000);
                 }
 } while(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to deal with this on a project of mine where the if statement would not branch correctly when using if without braces. The solution was using curly braces after if/else statements even if there was only one statement after it. It is a bug on the compiler.

```
         if(y<=0.8 && y>0.65)
                   temp_value = temp_value+10;
         else if(y<=0.65 && y>0.6)
              temp_value = temp_value+17.5;
```

becomes

```
         if(y<=0.8 && y>0.65){
                   temp_value = temp_value+10;
         }
         else if(y<=0.65 && y>0.6){
              temp_value = temp_value+17.5;
         }
```

If the program simply crashes, check the generated HEX/ASM.